# Does `('a':_)` represent a tuple or a list?

Tags: list, haskell

A function  that    decides if  a   list begins with    the letter  ’a’ can be  defined as  follows:

```
test :: [Char] -> Bool 
test ['a',_] = True  
test _ = False
```

or

```
test :: [Char] -> Bool 
test ('a':_) = True  
test _ = False
```

Why does the first use `[]`, while the second uses `()`?

Does the second use `('a':_)` to represent a tuple or a list?

- If a tuple, doesn't `test`'s argument  have a list type `[Char]`?
- If a list, doesn't `()` represent a tuple and how can it represent a list?

Comment: They both represent lists, and in fact are exactly the same pattern. `['a',_]` is syntactic sugar for `(a:_)` [Actually that's not quite true: `['a',_]` is a list of exactly 2 elements whose first is `a`, whereas the other is a list of any length which starts with `a`.]

Comment: The `(:)` is a data constructor of a list.

Comment: `( , , , )` are tuples, `[ , , , ]` are lists; parentheses have many uses and brackets have few.

Comment: No  comma, no tuple.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Does the second use `('a':_)` to represent a tuple or a list?

A **list**.

> If a list, doesn't `()` represent a tuple and how can it represent a list?

No, this is the [**unit type** [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_type). It is not a tuple, nor a list. Sometimes, as the Wikipedia article says, it is interpreted as an 0-tuple. It is defined in [**`GHC.Tuple`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.5.3/docs/GHC-Tuple.html#t:-40--41-) as well.

> Why does the first use `[]`, while the second uses `()`?

The two are *not* equivalent. The former one matches a list with *exactly* two elements where the first element is an `'a'`, whereas the latter matches a list with *at least one* element where the first element is an `'a'`. But the latter can match a list with one element, three elements, etc. whereas the former can only match lists with *exactly* two elements.

## Background

**`(:)`** is a *data constructor* of a list. Indeed:

```
Prelude> :i (:)
data [] a = ... | a : [a]   -- Defined in ‘GHC.Types’
infixr 5 :
```

The `('a': _)` is just a nicer form of `((:) 'a' _)`. We here thus use one of the list data constructors.

The `['a', _]` is syntactical sugar for `(:) 'a' ((:) _ [])`, so here we match a list that starts with an `'a'` and where the tail is a list with as head a value we do not care about and its tail the empty list *data constructor*.

Comment: I actually always think of the "unit type" `()` as indeed being a tuple, just one with zero elements. That's still a type with exactly one (non-bottom) value. And I think the wiki article you linked suggests this interpretation is legitimate. (But I don't think the OP was actually talking about unit when referring to `()`, they were just referring to the fact that tuples in general use parentheses. At least that's my interpretation.)

Comment: @RobinZigmond: one can indeed interpret it as an 0-tuple, since logically speaking an 0-tuple would have one data constructor with no parameters, and thus have one possible value. It is even defined in `GHC.Tuple` :)

Comment: Agreed - so I was surprised with your explicit insistence that `()` "is not a tuple".

Comment: @RobinZigmond moreover, in the algebra of types `(,)` is a product, and 1 is the multiplication's identity element (`a = a*1` ; `a <--> (a,())`). so it all ties up together nicely.

Answer (score 5):

Haskell's list notation is just syntactic sugar for "cons"ing elements on to the empty list (that is, using the `:` operator).

In other words,

```
[x,y,z]
```

is syntactic sugar for

```
x:(y:(z:[]))
```

(although this form would more normally be written as `x:y:z:[]` without the parentheses, since `:` is right-associative).

So, in the example you quote, `('a':_)` represents any list whose first element is `'a'`, while `['a',_]` is sugar for `(a:(_:[]))` which is a list of length exactly 2, whose first element is `a`.

Note that tuples are something else entirely, being denoted by a sequence of values in parentheses separated by commas.

Answer (score 1):

In Haskell there are data constructors that are symbols, some examples that may confuse you:

```
() :: ()
```

that's the type `unit` with its constructor `()` and its value `()`

then there is:

```
(,) :: a -> b -> (a,b)
```

`(,)` is the constructor for tuples, for example `(1,"b")` that can be `(1,) “b”` or `(,) 1 “b”`

finally your case:

```
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
```

for example, `1:[]` that can be `[1]` or `(:) 1 []`